# Constant and enum

Tags: c++, enums, constants, compiler-optimization

When we can use constant and enum? Is there any advantage over each other.

As per I know both are put in symbol table by the compiler, so that means both the ways are optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants can be any type (int, float, struct, etc.).

Enums are good when you have a list of mutually exclusive items, and don't particularly care about what value they have, just as long as they are mutually exclusive. Enums are only integers, so you cannot have a floating point enum.

Answer (score 0):

The difference really comes down to readibility for the programmer as well as type safety. Consider:

```
enum class Months : unsigned short {
    JAN = 1,
    FEB,
    MAR,
    .
    .
    .
    DEC
}; // compiler fills in the numbers for you.

typedef const int Month;
static Month JAN = 1;
static Month FEB = 2;
.
.
.
static Month DEC = 12;
```

Keep in mind that constants can also have any types whereas your enumerated type defaults to an `int` type (although that can be changed in C++11).

Comment: Ugh, all-upper-case constants.

Comment: You can specify an enum's type in C++11, but it still must be an integer type; floating point types, structs, and other enums aren't allowed as enum types.

Answer (score 0):

If the constant being used is an int, then they are effectively the same as far as the compiler is concerned. However, as user3470630 pointed out, constants can be of any type unlike enums which are always integers.

However, enums can be advantageous when it comes to code readability, since they allow you to define a set of related and mutually exclusive values.